# Where can I find indy 10 demos for each and every component?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Where Can I find demos for each and every component of Indy version 10 and for Delphi version 2010/XE/XE2.
I couldn't find any demos on their official website.
Also, I am not able to find any demo at all installed on my computer where I have installed Delphi 2010.

I am particularly interested in these 4 components: Telnet Server/Client and IRC Server/Client, but the question is for ALL the components of Indy.

Comment: Warren, with reference to the latest initiative to be more friendly to newcommers and the fact that George has a rep of 1 try to consider how it feels to have your first question called "useless".
P.S. I know you are not really being unkind, but it does come across that way.

Comment: Just trying to let George know the facts.  Hey George, Welcome aboard.

Comment: @Larsdk - It is a known fact. StackOverflow has the tendency of corrupting otherwise good people and make them snarky :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi does not ship with Indy demos.  The official documentation on [Indy's](https://www.indyproject.org/documentation/) website is a good start.

Comment: @Franz: thanks, I have added that link to the [Demos](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Demos/) page on Indy's website.

Comment: Can you please check the links. They are lead to a 404 page: http://ww2.indyproject.org/downloads/IndyDocs_10.1.5.0_H2Help.zip 

Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.
We can’t connect to the server at ww2.indyproject.org.

Comment: @GabrielM known issue: [Links to old Indy website pages are currently broken](https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/)